# How to compose a large 64-bit number out of smaller 4 or 16-bit numbers

Tags: javascript, integer, bit-manipulation, bit

Wondering how you can take an array of small numbers *that represent a larger number*, and convert it into that larger number, and vice versa.

I'm not really sure how to actually represent this, but the gist of it is as follows.

Say you have a bunch of 4-bit numbers:

```
[ 3, 2, 5, 13, 2, 8, 1, ... ]
```

Wondering how to calculate the final number. Not really sure what I mean totally, but what I'm trying to get at is... I don't want to just *add* the numbers:

```
3 + 2 + 5 + 13 + 2 + 8 + 1 = 34
```

And I don't want to just merge the bits.

```
00000011 + 00000010 + 00000101 + ...
(3)      + (2)      + (5)      + ...
=
000000110000001000000101
```

I instead want to reverse the following process. Say I have a large number like `2147483650` (slightly more than a 32-bit integer). I want to store that integer in an array of 4-bit chunks. Maybe those chunks look like this:

```
[ 3, 2, 5, 13, 2, 8, 1, ... ]
```

So that's the main goal. How to:

1. Convert a large number into an array of smaller numbers.
2. How to convert the array of small numbers into a single large number.

But maybe the large integer is 32 bits, and the small integers are 2 bits, or maybe they are 8 bits, etc. Basically a generic way to say:

```
function divideLargeIntoArrayOfSmall(integer, smallBitSize) {
  if (smallBitSize == 4) {
    return integer.splitIntoBitChunksOf(4)
  } else if (smallBitSize == 2) {
    return integer.splitIntoBitChunksOf(2)
  } else if (smallBitSize == 8) {
    return integer.splitIntoBitChunksOf(8)
  } else if (smallBitSize == 16) {
    return integer.splitIntoBitChunksOf(16)
  }
}

function composeIntoSingleLarge(array, itemBitSize) {
  if (itemBitSize == 4) {
    // array.sum(integerFromBitSize(4))
  } else if (itemBitSize == 2) {
    // array.sum(integerFromBitSize(2))
  } else if (itemBitSize == 8) {
    // array.sum(integerFromBitSize(8))
  } else if (itemBitSize == 16) {
    // array.sum(integerFromBitSize(16))
  }
}
```

Comment: Shift. Need more characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode integers into other integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227279/how-to-encode-integers-into-other-integers) (your own question)